# Obtain DeviceId in Http Header

Tags: http, charles-proxy

I used Charles to check the request header when I login to the phone app and noticed that the DeviceId in the Header is different both time, I am a bit confused on this as how would I get a different DeviceId if I was using the same device for both time?

Also, when I try to write my own request header, what can I put for the DeviceId field?

I put the header below:

```
    headers ={
    'Host': 'prod-t2-api.adia.com',
    'Accept':'*/*',
    'server_version': '36',
    'RequestFrom': 'Candidate',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'client_version': '2.0.47',
    'platform': 'IOS',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    #'Content-Length': '87',
    'DeviceId': '365C96E6-B22A-41FA-B569-BAF68E5F60FE',
    'IsoCountryCode': 'US',
    'User-Agent': 'Adia/300 CFNetwork/1325.0.1 Darwin/21.1.0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think DeviceId is a standard header. So it's just something set by the specific application you're trying to debug. I don't believe there is a general answer to this.

Comment: So if you work at (I presume) 'adia', as a co-worker, if you're trying to reverse engineer their API... good luck =)